# How to select all elements that have another element in their list

Tags: hibernate, orm, hql, spring-orm

I'm new to hibernate and can't RTFM so I hope someone can help save me a lot of time.

I have a many-to-many relationship between objects in my database. Let's say Employees and Jobs.

I want to select all Jobs assigned to a given employee. My object Jobs has a list of all employees who are working on it. So, in java, it'd be: Job job.employees.contains(employee). Except I need to turn this into a hibernate query or something.

Right now I'm doing brute force in Java after just selecting everything.

```
  getJobsByEmployee(Employee selectedEmployee) {
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Job");
    List<Job> allJobs = query.getResultList();

    List<Job> emplJobs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Job job : allJobs) {
      for (Employee empl : job.getEmployees()) {
        if (empl.getId() == selectedEmployee.getId()) {
          emplJObs.add(job);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return emplJobs;
  }
```

How do I write a query or HQL or otherwise just get the data from my DB for this? I've only written the most basic queries to date and am overwhelmed with all the different syntax options in hibernate.

PS I'm using Spring ORM so some normal hibernate syntax might be missing due to being transactional, etc.

Please don't ask me why I'm doing it this way. I have to.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the answer was so obvious I couldn't see it.

Just return the jobs that are already on the employee object. Since it's many to many it also has a list of jobs.

```
  return selectedEmployee.getJobs();
```

duh. had to call size() first since the jobs property on employee was not eagerly loaded...